# Multiple Select Statements in R Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I want to have the year column selected too in the output but I dont understand how to add another column in the select statement. The column I want to select is a simple column named "Year".

Following is the code I am trying to use but it gives me an error. The select_if condition is correct because if I do not add the "select("Year")" line the code works fine.
Please help

```
Subset <-df %>% 
select("Year") & select_if(grepl("Apple", names(.)))
```

Comment: You don't need quotes in your select. `select(Year, otherColumn, \`Column with Space\`)`

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, contains("gea")) %>%
  head()

                  cyl gear
Mazda RX4           6    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       6    4
Datsun 710          4    4
Hornet 4 Drive      6    3
Hornet Sportabout   8    3
Valiant             6    3
```